# How to copy folder to new location and give it a timestamp

Tags: file, batch-file

So I want to copy a folder called 'batchOS', then move the copied version to AppData Roaming and give it a timestamp. I looked at other questions like this, but none worked like I want it to.

So basically in AppData Roaming folder a folder should appear called batchOS-11-13-2012 (example).

Comment: Maybe you couldn't find an exact match, but at least you should have been able to use multiple posts to get what you want right?

Comment: No, I tried a ton of things using many methods and so far none have worked. Zip. Zero. I even tried using different directories, different code, etc.

Comment: It would help to share the things you tried and the problems you were hit by when trying.

Comment: :attempt
rem Get the current date
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime') do if not defined LocalDateTime set LocalDateTime=%%x
set MyDate=%LocalDateTime:~0,8%

rem Create folder
set batchOS=C:\Users\%username%\batchBackup\%MyDate%-batchOS
mkdir %batchOS%

rem Copy files
xcopy /s c:\Users\%username%\Documents\batchOS\ c:\Users\%username%\batchBackup\batchOS-%MyDate%\

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13370271/edit) your question :-)

Comment: Instead of even responding with why it wasn't working, why not just respond with an answer? LOL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in a batchfile it should work:

```
@Echo Off
@For /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
    Set Day=%%A
    Set Month=%%B
    Set Year=%%C
    Set All=%%C%%B%%A
    )
echo d | xcopy /f /y "Directory\BatchOS" "DestinationDirectory\BatchOS%ALL%" /E
```

Replace Directory with the directory of the folder. And destination directory with where you want it.

EDIT: Added in this part so it does not prompt you. Tested it works. echo d | xcopy /f /y